# set a map to a parameterclass in iBatis

Tags: ibatis, sqlmap

what's the difference between setting a map and setting an object to a parameterClass in iBatis?

means,

```
<update id="update" parameterClass="map">
    UPDATE city 
    SET province_id = #province_id#
    WHERE id = #id# 
</update>
```

and

```
<update id="update" parameterClass="City">
    UPDATE city 
    SET province_id = #province_id#
    WHERE id = #id# 
</update>
```

?

I could not find any difference when I tested both.

I really want to set all with "map", but scared ...

Comment: What do you mean by "I could not find any difference when I tested both"? The map case should pass a Map instance while the second one should pass a City instance.

Comment: City object has types for each elements (long province_id, long id)  while the map passes only values ( {"province_id", "19283"}, {"id", "32787"} ). I wondered how iBatis knows the type of the parameters if I use a map<String, String (or Object)> to quote in SQL. Anyway it works, but I am scared.....

Answer (score 0):

"map" in `parameterClass="map"` simply is an alias for "java.util.Map".
Don't you think it is simply because your City class implements the Map interface?

Comment: when use "City" as parameter, ibatis passes [Long, Int, String] as they are set. But if I use 'map' as parameter, ibatis passes [String, String, String] though it still works. My inquiry is "is there absolutely no problem with sending arguments without proper types?"